# How to present row data in JSON format in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to present the data which is getting after joined with another table. It is getting multiple records for one particular Id. So I want to display those multiple records in JSON format.

I have the below data.

```
Declare @Employees Table (EmpId int, EmpName Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Employees
VALUES(1,'RAM')
,(2,'RAJ')
,(3,'LAXMAN')

    Declare @Subjects Table (EmpId int, Subject Varchar(100))
    INSERT INTO @Subjects
    VALUES(1,'Maths')
    ,(1,'Science')
    ,(1,'Physics')
    ,(2,'Physics')
    ,(3,'Maths')
    ,(3,'Physics')
```

I have tried with this query.

```
SELECT E.EmpId
    ,Subject
FROM @Employees E
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT EmpId
        ,'{' + STUFF((
                SELECT ',"' + NULLIF(Subject, '') + '"'
                FROM @Subjects AS CG1
                WHERE CG1.EmpId = CG2.EmpId
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '') + '}' AS Subject
    FROM @Subjects AS CG2
    GROUP BY EmpId
    ) SUB ON SUB.EmpId = E.EmpId
```

But I want the result like this.

```
    EmpId   Subject
-----------------------------------------------------
    1       {"1":"Maths","2":"Science","3":"Physics"}
    2       {"1":"Physics"}
    3       {"1":"Maths","2":"Physics"}
```

Please let me know if you want any further information is needed.
I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: The "ideal" option would be to upgrade your SQL Server version to one that supports JSON (and isn't in extended support).

Comment: Another option would be to let the *client* convert the data to JSON

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, you need to add a `ROW_NUMBER` to the subquery too. I've also switched to `CONCAT` for easy implicit conversions:

```
SELECT E.EmpId,
       Subject
FROM @Employees E
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmpId,
                       '{' + STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',"', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CG1.Subject), '":"', NULLIF(Subject, ''), '"')
                                    FROM @Subjects CG1
                                    WHERE CG1.EmpId = CG2.EmpId
                                    ORDER BY Subject
                                    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + '}' AS Subject
                FROM @Subjects CG2
                GROUP BY EmpId) SUB ON SUB.EmpId = E.EmpId;
```

Note that the order of the subjects in your table isn't preserved, due to that there is no way to preserve it with an `ORDER BY` (at least not with the data we have). Therefore `'Physics'` has a number of `2` instead of `3` for `Empid` `1`

Comment: Subject should be NULL if there is no subject for EmpId. But with this query I am getting EmpId in Quotes.

Comment: There are no rows with that scenario in your sample, @sasibhushan . i can't cater for a scenario I don't know about. Include *all* the scenarios and all the information we need to answer your question; don't move the goal posts after you get an answer, please.

Comment: But, if there are no subjects for the user then the subquery will return no rows, so it would return `NULL`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fcfce1d2d380589fcb6999eac92fc19e)